# Why combined data structures in c++ have a lower performance than independent arrays

Tags: c++, performance, structure

Here is my test code compiled in Linux with command

> g++ main.cpp -O3 -o stest

I tried two ways to combine datas(**test2** **test3**). But, both the two ways failed to have a better performance as I expected. In my view, combined datas should have a better performance than independent arrays, because the higher cache loads datas from lower cache by block. So, the combined datas have more chances to be loaded in one memory access. However, the independent arrays(**test1**) needs three memory accesses. But, the test results showed that **test1** has the best performance. It's too strange for me. And, I don't know why. If you know, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

tms start, tEnd;

long long test1(int n) {
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[n];
    int *c = new int[n];


    times(&start);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += c[i];
    }

    times(&tEnd);

    double elap_time = double(tEnd.tms_utime - start.tms_utime + tEnd.tms_stime - start.tms_stime) / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
    cout << "test1: " << elap_time << "ms  result=" << sum << " " << endl;
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    return sum;
}

struct D {
    int a, b, c;
};

long long test2(int n) {
    struct D *d = new D[n];

    times(&start);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        struct D &di = d[i];
        di.a = di.b = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        struct D &di = d[i];
        di.c = di.a + di.b;
    }
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += d[i].c;
    }

    times(&tEnd);
    double elap_time = double(tEnd.tms_utime - start.tms_utime + tEnd.tms_stime - start.tms_stime) / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
    cout << "test2: " << elap_time << "ms  result=" << sum << " " << endl;
    delete [] d;
    return sum;
}

long long test3(int n) {
    int *abc = new int[3 * n];

    times(&start);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int base = 3 * i;
        abc[base] = abc[base + 1] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int base = 3 * i;
        abc[base + 2] = abc[base] + abc[base + 1];
    }

    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += abc[3 * i + 2];
    }

    times(&tEnd);
    double elap_time = double(tEnd.tms_utime - start.tms_utime + tEnd.tms_stime - start.tms_stime) / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
    cout << "test3: " << elap_time << "ms  result=" << sum << " " << endl;
    delete [] abc;
    return sum;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 9999999;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    test1(n);
    test2(n);
    test3(n);

    cout<<"after changing order"<<endl;

    test2(n);
    test3(n);
    test1(n);

    cout<<"after changing order"<<endl;
    test3(n);
    test1(n);
    test2(n);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested **stest** in a computer with four i5-4460 CPU and a **8GB** memory. Here is the command I used to test the program, and I'm sure that with a parameter **399999999**, the computer won't get out of memory:

```
q@q-lab:~/Desktop$ ./stest 399999999
test1: 1.61ms  result=159999998800000002 
test2: 2.38ms  result=159999998800000002 
test3: 2.37ms  result=159999998800000002 
after changing order
test2: 2.38ms  result=159999998800000002 
test3: 2.38ms  result=159999998800000002 
test1: 1.61ms  result=159999998800000002 
after changing order
test3: 2.38ms  result=159999998800000002 
test1: 1.61ms  result=159999998800000002 
test2: 2.39ms  result=159999998800000002
```

Comment: Your question is missing your results. Is the performance the same or different if you change the order each is done in?

Comment: One word: SIMD.

Comment: [Results](http://quick-bench.com/TfZ59ZcvU9xZi6jT6GCg7mHUUNI) from http://quick-bench.com

Comment: Thanks for your remind. I have append my results. And the order doesn't matter the conclusion. The Results from quick-bench.com by Jarod42 also have the same conclusion: independent arrays is faster than combined data structure.

Comment: I did more test on quick-bench.com, and I found that after I introduce some **random effect** into the test, combined datas have a obivious better performance than independent arrays. [Results with random effect](http://quick-bench.com/thLCklC-7inKtPIq8Yr0hlwyGHo) from [quick-bench.com](quick-bench.com)

Answer (score -1):

Combine data need more time to Addressing or calculating data offset.
And, CPU cache is unpredictable and difficult to optimize. It is best not to try to optimize the CPU cache.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, I think It's a natural thinking that calculating data offset is much faster than load datas from memory.